# Login screen shown just once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, authentication

i'm making app based on tab bar with two tabs. My problem is that i have to implement authentication view "loginView" on one of tabb's view, and when the credentials are saved i want show another data everytime tab is tapped. what's the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a boolean in your user defaults, something like 'loginShown', then, in your `appplicationDidFinishLaunching` method, check if the 'loginShown' is set, and if not, present a **modal** view controller which is your login view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `modalViewController` for Login so you can have some other view beneath it. For saving credentials for Login so that the user does not have to log back in, you can store it in the `KeyChain`.

Use this reference: http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

Comment: OK, i tried to o it this way (with modalViewController) but I had big problem, I mean when i dismiss modal view controller by clicking "Cancel" button program redirect to Tab which is selected with secure data under login view and i want to redirect to another tab. I tried with delegate but that doesn't work.

Comment: tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex = 0 is first tab. Set value to 1 for second tab and stuff like that.